# Perl split file into columns with unix command

Tags: perl, command-line, tabs, warnings

I have a file with various columns separated by tabs.
I' trying to invoke an unix command in perl but it gives me an error ever time

```
use strict;
use warnings;


system ("awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' file.txt > first_field.tmp");
```

Comment: What error does it throw back?

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at q4.pl line 11. except I don't want to initialize $1. the program should know its the 2nd column

Answer (score 3):

Single quote your [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command:

```
system(q{awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' file.txt > first_field.tmp});
```

Or without the need for an external resource:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

{
    local @ARGV = 'file.txt';
    open my $fh, '>', 'first_field.tmp';
    while (<>) {
        chomp;
        my @F = split "\t";
        $fh->print("$F[0]\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a native Perl solution. I can't wholeheartedly endorse my own answer telling someone to call AWK from Perl!

Comment: ty, I am hoping that "spent an hour on this" is a wee bit of hyperbole, as doing this doesn't even take a minute.  I'm sure there ARE times that using one of the many awesome unix utilties is the right solution, but if someone is starting a project in perl, I tend to feel they should stick with that unless there's a specific reason not to.  Since adding external dependencies makes code more fragile. Just my .02 :)  ... Nice eagle eyes to sport the original issue btw

Answer (score 2):

You have a tab-separated value file. What's wrong with `Text::CSV` in tab-separated mode then? No need to invoke `awk` for something like this.

Comment: +1 Good idea to use Text::CSV. I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using double quotes `" "` around your command, Perl is trying to interpolate the value of `$1`. You need to escape it:

```
system ("awk -F '\t' '{print \$1}' file.txt > first_field.tmp");
```

Or you could use `'` quotes, which don't interpolate:

```
system ('awk -F "\t" "{print $1}" file.txt > first_field.tmp');
```

...or `qx`:

```
qx/awk -F '\t' '{print \$1}' file.txt > first_field.tmp/;
```

Seeing as you're such a big fan of Perl, I would recommend checking out the documentation regarding the various types of [quotes and quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Obviously this is the kind of thing that Perl eats for breakfast, so if you're looking for a native solution I would recommend using what @Miller has posted, or one of the million other ways you could do the same thing in Perl.

An alternative version using the [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) package as suggested by @LeoNerd:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    use Text::CSV;

    my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => "\t" } )
                    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

    open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die "file.txt: $!";
    open my $out, ">", "first_field.tmp" or die "first_field.tmp: $!";
    while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
        $out->print("$row->[0]\n");
    }
    $csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
}
```

Comment: I was about to write this Tom Fenech! :-)

Comment: it's just frustrating

Comment: @user3357980 happy to help but you might ruffle a few feathers by swearing in the comments...

Comment: @user3357980: The problems you're having really have nothing to do with Perl. Expanding variables in a double-quoted string is a common feature across many Unix utilities.